# WatchOS2 Event Complication, how to step to next event at endTime of prior event? (getTimelineEntriesForComplication)

Tags: ios, swift, watchos-2, apple-watch-complication

As title says, at end of a watch Event complication, ModularLarge, as Apple's Calendar complication does, say Event is 7-7:10pm, then next event is 8pm.  So at Time Travel, or even on watch face itself live, when Event end Time occurs, I do not step/display the next event(I have event in the array note). Think I am just missing something. Note: I am a bit new at this. Here is the code I have.

```
func getTimelineEntriesForComplication(complication: CLKComplication, afterDate date: NSDate, limit: Int, withHandler handler: (([CLKComplicationTimelineEntry]?) -> Void)) {
        // Call the handler with the timeline entries after to the given date

        var timeLineEntryArray = [CLKComplicationTimelineEntry]()

        if allEvents.count > 0 {

             for (index, title) in allEvents.enumerate() {

                let item = allEvents[index]   
                let startDate = item.startDate
                let endDate = item.endDate
                let title = item.title

                //let entry = createTimeLineEntry2(timeString, body1Text: timeLineText[index], body2Text: timeUntilArray[index], date: nextDate)

                 let entry = createTimeLineEntry2(timeString, body1Text: title, body2Text: timeUntil, startDate: startDate)

                timeLineEntryArray.append(entry)

            } //end for loop...

        } //end If allEvents.count > 0 we have events

        handler(timeLineEntryArray)
    }
```

so at watch time, and TimeTravel of 7:11 should display the 8pm Event, and then I desire to delta time to shot time until that event. so "-49 minutes" with this code that works:

```
func createTimeLineEntry2(headerText: String, body1Text: String, body2Text: String, startDate: NSDate) -> CLKComplicationTimelineEntry {
 template.body2TextProvider = CLKRelativeDateTextProvider(date: startDate,
                                                             style: .Offset,
                                                             units: NSCalendarUnit.Hour.union(.Minute))
        template.body2TextProvider!.tintColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        template.tintColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        let entry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: startDate, complicationTemplate: template)
    return(entry)
}
```

Lastly, can we set the tint(color) of the body2TextProvider?

thank you so much. Mike

here is a link to picture, this event ended at 9:10 am, so watch shodld show the 12 pm event now!  http://pics.derr.ws/watch.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [watchOS - Complication shows previous entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37929938/watchos-complication-shows-previous-entry)

Comment: yes Petah thanks, watching video now! Might you have idea off hand what i need to add to get next event to show on timeline at end of prior event? AS you see events have .endDate :) Hope I can solve it! Might you have idea on how to set the tint for body2Text line?

Comment: As the video and [existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37929938/watchos-complication-shows-previous-entry) already explains, you set the upcoming timeline entry to start one minute after the end date for the previous event.  So your 8:00 timeline entry should have a start time of 7:11, not 8:00.